Как в asp net core сделать так, чтобы при валидации выводились ошибки на русском языке?
В моем коде данные проверяются через ModelState.IsValid. Если пользователь с таким логином уже есть в бд, то появляется ошибка на английском языке, а мне нужно чтобы она была на русском.

Тут есть три варианта.

Вы можете подключить локализацию и использовать сообщения об ошибке как ключ в таблице переводов, что бы получать текст ошибки на выбранном языке (не только на русском)

Вы можете использовать сторонние библиотеки, такие как FluentValidation. В том же FluentValidation есть список ошибок, которые выводятся в зависимости от системного языка пользователя (Что-то на подобии встроенно локализации по простому)

Выводить ошибку на русском языке. Серьёзно?. Да, вы можете хард-кодом (Или константами) прописать нужную вам ошибку, в том числе на русском языке и просто возвращать её вместе с респонсом, записывать в БД, логировать и т.д.


